# Sum of UTF-16 character codes

Tags: javascript, utf-16

I'm starting by apologising if this seems a easy question but for me is not. Just started to learn JavaScript :)

So my question is how to return the sum of the values of UTF-16 character codes, e.g. if 'A'=65, 'AB'[A+B] = [65+66] = 131, 'ABC' - [A+B+C] = [65+66+67] will return 198 or 'Hello World' = [H+e+l+l+o+W+o+r+l+d] in UTF-16 will result whatever it is adding all values and so on... I have to create a function to return the sum of the values of UTF-16 codes.

I think I have to make use of *charCodeAt();* but I don't know how to achieve this...

Thanks in advance for any reply

Comment: Yes. Use a loop over the character indices, from 0 to the string's length, and sum the character codes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can use `TextEncoder()` and `Array.prototype.reduce()`. Note, the result would be `198`, not `193`

```js
let str = "ABC";
let res = [...new TextEncoder().encode(str)].reduce((a, b) => a + b);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: OP did specifically ask for UTF16 though

Comment: @Bergi See OP at _"(65+66+67)"_ , _"I have to make use of charCodeAt(0)"_. How is UTF16 related to Question and expected result?

Comment: Well the OP explicitly asked about the "*values of UTF-16 character codes*". That the UTF8 bytes have the same values for the example `ABC` is just coincidence.

Comment: @Bergi There are no coincidences as to anything on this plane of existence. JavaScript uses UTF-16 internally anyway http://es5.github.io/x2.html#x2. `String.prototype.charCodeAt()` returns same result as code at Answer. Since you are making a point of attempting to distinguish between UTF-8 and UTF-16 as to character encoding you need to describe the difference between the two, else your input at the present Question and Answer lacks substantial merit.

Comment: I'm sure you can look up the difference between UTF-8 and UTF-16 yourself. Don't use UTF-8 in your code!

Comment: @Bergi Have been doing so and cannot locate what you are trying to infer at comments; as if the Answer is somehow not correct, when the expected result is returned. When you post as if you are a teacher you need to teach, and not be conservative with your posture as to the minutia within the details. If the expected result is not `198`, then what is the expected result?

Comment: Even though the answer works for the value "ABC", it does not work for all UTF16 input strings - which surely is expected. I don't think you need me to find a counterexample.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, you are needed to find a counterexample. You are the individual who are pointing out the differences - don't teach halfway if you are going to put yourself out there as a teacher. Then the "downvote" has merit, being backed with actual evidence. Presently you are only indicating a potential issue without thoroughly describing the parameters of the potential issues that you mention in passing, half-way

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
<script>
    var letras = "ABC";
    var soma = 0;

    letras.split('').forEach(function (letra) {
        soma+=letra.charCodeAt(0);
    });
    console.log(soma);
</script>
//return 198
```